# Select rows that have two columns the same but another different if they have multiple tuples

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a database table with these columns:

```
local  domain  email_sha256  password  password_sha256
a      b       ...           C         ...
a      bb      ...           C         ...
a      bb      ...           CC        ...
a      bbb     ...           C         ...
aa     bb      ...           CCC       ...
aa     bb      ...           CC        ...
```

The `local` and `domain` part are essentially email that have been split at the @ character.

> test@gmail.com
>
> local = test
>
> domain = gmail.com

I want to find all rows that have the same `local` and `password` pair, but have a different `domain`. This would return something like if I only take the `local`, `domain`, and `password` columns

```
local  domain  password
a      b       C
a      bb      C
a      bbb     C
```

I have been trying to first identify all pairs of `local`, `password` that have duplicates, with:

```
SELECT local, password 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY local, password
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Now to get more columns than just the `GROUP BY` I do a `JOIN` on the table itself

```
SELECT local, domain, password 
FROM tablename
JOIN (SELECT local, domain FROM tablename GROUP BY local, password HAVING count(*) > 1)
USING (local, password)
```

Now to make sure the that the domain is different I once again join the table on itself and add a `WHERE` clause. To avoid repetition I use a `GROUP BY`. Here is my final query.

```
SELECT A.local, A.domain, A.password
FROM tablename as A
JOIN 
    (SELECT  local, domain, password 
    FROM tablename
    JOIN 
        (SELECT local, password 
        FROM tablename 
        GROUP BY local, password 
        HAVING count(*) > 1) 
    USING (local, password)) as B
USING (local, password)
WHERE A.password = B.password AND A.domain != B.domain AND A.local = B.local
GROUP BY local, domain, password
ORDER BY local, password
```

Am I removing potential valid results with this query? Also, is there is a faster/better query to run and achieve the same result?

Thanks.

Note: This table has no unique id's, but I probably don't have duplicate `email_sha256`, `password_sha256` pairs so they can be used as id's.

Comment: Seems my query returns the same values as the awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH remove_dup_domains AS (
  SELECT rec.* FROM (
    SELECT local, domain, password, ANY_VALUE(t) rec
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
    GROUP BY local, domain, password
  )
)
SELECT y.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t) bin 
  FROM remove_dup_domains t
  GROUP BY local, password
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)x, x.bin y
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' local, 'b' domain, 'C' password, 'whatever else1' other_cols UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'C', 'whatever else2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'CC', 'whatever else3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'bbb', 'C', 'whatever else4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'bbbb', 'D', 'whatever else5' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 'bbbbb', 'E', 'whatever else6' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aa', 'bb', 'CCC', 'whatever else7' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aa', 'bb', 'CC', 'whatever else8' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa', 'com', 'H', 'whatever else9' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa', 'com', 'H', 'whatever else10' 
), remove_dup_domains AS (
  SELECT rec.* FROM (
    SELECT local, domain, password, ANY_VALUE(t) rec
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
    GROUP BY local, domain, password
  )
)
SELECT y.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t) bin 
  FROM remove_dup_domains t
  GROUP BY local, password
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)x, x.bin y
```

with result

```
Row local   domain  password    other_cols   
1   a       b       C           whatever else1   
2   a       bb      C           whatever else2   
3   a       bbb     C           whatever else4
```

Comment: How does this guarantee that the domain is different for tuples of local, password? I am not interested in local, domain pairs that have a single domain.

Comment: Whats the point of the x, x.bin y in the last select? If I dont want the ANY_VALUE in the final table what can I remove?

Comment: `x.bin y` is a shortcut for `UNNEST(bin) y` - you can see both UNNEST and shortcut versions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565147/5221944 - upvote that one if it helped to understand this "trick"

Comment: `ANY_VALUE(t) rec` just preserves thw whole row for you so you can then output all columns in final result. If you need ONLY `local, domain, password` - you can just remove that piece :o)

Comment: What is the point of the ARRAY_AGG(t), I don't understand what its doin? Also, finally understand the ANY_VALUE trick I love it, no need to use a  join on my table ever again! Great trick with the x, x.bin y to unset the array, just a little confusing since you doing three things in such concise way (name table=x, unset x, rename unset value to y, am i wrong?)

Comment: `ARRAY_AGG(t)` collect all records/rows from table `t` GROUP'ed BY local, password and leaved only those with more than one records. this one is than being unnested in outer query ;o)  I know it can be a little complicated for first time  - but it is important to fully get it so then it will fly - so thank you for asking follow-up "how" type of questions here ;o)

Comment: Could I of avoided the `ARRAY_AGG + x, x.bin y` with `ANY_VALUE` and still use the `GROUP BY + HAVING`?

Comment: I think this will not fly (unfortunately) - but you can try by yourself using dummy example as in my answer! as I said there - you can test and PLAY with it on your own

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find all rows that have the same local and password pair, but have a different domain.

I think you can do:

```
select t.* except (min_domain, max_domain)
from (select t.*,
             min(domain) over (partition by local, password) as min_domain,
             max(domain) over (partition by local, password) as max_domain
      from tablename t
     ) t
where min_domain <> max_domain;
```

Comment: nope! try with sample data like `SELECT 'a' local, 'b' domain, 'C' password, 'whatever else1' other_cols UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'C', 'whatever else2' UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'bb', 'C', 'whatever else3' UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'bbb', 'C', 'whatever else4' UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'bbbb', 'C', 'whatever else5' UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 'bbbb', 'C', 'whatever else6'  `