# Cannot access field permission on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<resource STRING, permission STRING, granted BOOL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to run this query (mytable not the real table name):

[image]

Getting this error: `Cannot access field permission on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<resource STRING, permission STRING, granted BOOL, ...>> at [2:41]`

It says in the schema it's just a string:

[image]

When I preview the table it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from below schema - `protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo` is an array

[image]

So, for you to access element of the array you should first UNNEST it as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT x.permission
FROM `your_table`,
UNNEST(protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo) x
LIMIT 10
```

with result as

[image]

Note: the shortcut version of UNNEST'ing in above query is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT x.permission
FROM `your_table` t,
t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo x
LIMIT 10
```

> Update for `how do I concat it to a comma separated string?`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT permission FROM t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo), ',') permissions
FROM `your_table` t
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: how do I concat it to a comma separated string? I want to get this as a single field and return other fields (like the bucket name)

Comment: ok, also where do I see the correct schema like your screenshot? Is it only visible in the old UI? Why does the new UI not show that?

Comment: good question! the way schema presented in my answer is not available in Google Web UI - not Classic nor New one. I am using Goliath for BigQuery - so screenshot is from there. You can try it for free - check it on Google Cloud Marketplace - [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) - Also you can read about features of the tools [here](https://potensio.zendesk.com). Disclosure - see my badge - I am an author and architect for the Potens.io  - set of productivity web based tools like Magus and Goliath. As  well as chrome extension BigQuery Mate.

Comment: I could ask another question for this, but how do you get "granted" in that? Im trying the same array_to_string and its not working. Is it because granted is boolean?

Comment: you really should ask new question explaining your specific case with all examples and logic you need to achieve - comments are not good for Q&A type of things. Please do post new question - and for sure you will get answer! Obviously try to ask your question such that you will not need to re-ask for each and every small addition :o)